# copy visible unique values excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy, unique

I have a data table `Table1`, and this table is usually filtered for one column or another. Behind a button I have code that should select data from the `Table1` in the column `Account Country`, only get the unique country values, copy the visible data, and paste them sorted alphabetically somewhere else. The problem I have is that I can't manage to combine unique with visible.

I have this code that is able to copy unique country labels

```
Dim tbl1 As ListObject
Set tbl1 = Worksheets("Daily work").ListObjects("Table1")

                       With tbl1.Sort
                            .SortFields.Clear
                            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Account Country]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
                            , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                            .Header = xlYes
                            .Apply
                        End With
                        
                        Worksheets("Daily work").Range("Table1[[#All],[Account Country]]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("A1006"), Unique:=True
                        Application.GoTo Reference:="Table1"
                        Selection.AutoFilter
```

however, it seems to copy also not visible country values from the table.

I've attempted to add `'.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)'` to the code section that copies, but it doesn't seem to work. I get this result, even though I know there is enough data left. The other image shows the data left visible after filtering has occurred. *The filter can be different based on what the user has done in the workbook, so I can't add the filtering to the code here*

[image]
[image]

Comment: _Instead_ of your Advanced Filter you can copy the visible cells with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` and then, on the destination range, call the [RemoveDuplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) method

Comment: The downside of that is that the visible cells could be 100s, and the unique ones only 2 to 4 values.

Comment: that's simply a function of your data, not the suggested methodology - if you go for a Dictionary then you could have 100s of 'range read' operations vs only 1 if you employ the clipboard

Comment: I have not tested on a larger scale, but I can adjust the code if need be for decreasing 
the process time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AdvancedFilter on top of AutoFilter (for what I know) so you either need to use the method @Spectral Instance mentioned or use a Dictionary to store the unique values if you don't want to use the clipboard:

```
Sub testAdvancedFilterUnique()
    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Dim arr()
    Dim rng As Range, ccell As Range
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set tbl1 = Worksheets("Daily work").ListObjects("Table1")

    With tbl1.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Account Country]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
        , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("Daily work")
        Set rng = .Range("Table1[[#All],[Account Country]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        For Each ccell In rng
            dict(ccell.Value) = Empty 'if it doesn't exist yet, add it
        Next
        
        arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys())
        .Range("A1006").Resize(UBound(arr, 1)).Value = arr 'paste all values in one go
    End With
    
 '    Application.Goto Reference:="Table1"
 '    Selection.AutoFilter
     
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Notus! I will test this as soon as I have time for it

Comment: works like a charm Notus! no more unnecessary steps going over unique values that were in the invisible , filter out data in my code.